# logstash: Trying to make sense of strings passed by IntelMQ in ElasticSearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, unicode, logstash

I have been trying to pass data from `IntelMQ` to `elasticsearch` 5.0 using `logstash` via `redis`.

One of the problems is that I receive in bulk in the `elasticsearch` side this string in a field called `message`.

```
{u'feed': u'openbl', u'reported_source_ip': u'115.79.215.79', u'source_cymru_cc': u'VN', u'source_time': u'2016-06-25T11:15:14+00:00', u'feed_url': u'http://www.openbl.org/lists/date_all.txt', u'taxonomy': u'Other', u'observation_time': u'2016-11-20T22:51:25', u'source_ip': u'115.79.215.79', u'source_registry': u'apnic', u'source_allocated': u'2008-07-17', u'source_bgp_prefix': u'115.79.192.0/19', u'type': u'blacklist', u'source_as_name': u'VIETEL-AS-AP Viettel Corporation, VN', u'source_asn':u'7552'}
```

Unfortunately, the particular fork of our CERT community is based in python 2.7, and there is no way around migrating to a new fork based in python 3.0 to get rid easily of the unicode marks before the strings.

My present `logstash` configuration is as follows:

```
filter {
  geoip {
    source => "source_ip"
  }
}
input { 
  redis {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    key => "iscte-redis-queue" 
    data_type => "list"
    codec => "json"
    db => "2"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => "127.0.0.1" }
}
```

Obviously, I need to rework that `filter` directive. I though of using the kv logstash filter, however that u mark renders this approach ineffective.

If it weren't from the unicode mark, I would try this:

```
filter {
  kv {
    source => "message"
    field_split => ", "
    trim => "\'"
  }
}
```

Grok rules are not entirely ruled out, however the fields vary, and would oblige me to write a rule to each different bot, based on the 'feed' field.

I am tempted to hack the IntelMQ source to get rid of that unicode mark, however I am taping into your opinions to see if there is a more efective way to handle the processing of this data.

I also am not entirely familiar with `logstash`, how to avoid it generating an entry in redis to each new, and putting it all back into one message where `elasticsearch` will know all the different variables?

So have you any suggestions?

Comment: How about using `mutate/gsub` to replace the `u` characters by an empty string?

Comment: Does it work? I cannot get rid of all the `u` characters.

Comment: Can you show your updated config?

Comment: My config is still as I show it...Still not sure how to go around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my suggestion: use the [`mutate/gsub`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub) filter in order to get rid or the `u` and `'` characters. That will produce a clean string that you can run through the `kv` filter.

```
filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => [
       "message", "{", "",
       "message", "}", "",
       "message", "u'", "", 
       "message", "',", ",", 
       "message", "':", ":"
    ]
  }
  kv {
    source => "message"
    field_split => ", "
    value_split => ": "
  }
}
```

You'll get a nice event like this one:

```
{
               "message" => "feed: openbl, reported_source_ip: 115.79.215.79, source_cymru_cc: VN, source_time: 2016-06-25T11:15:14+00:00, feed_url: http://www.openbl.org/lists/date_all.txt, taxonomy: Other, observation_time: 2016-11-20T22:51:25, source_ip: 115.79.215.79, source_registry: apnic, source_allocated: 2008-07-17, source_bgp_prefix: 115.79.192.0/19, type: blacklist, source_as_name: VIETEL-AS-AP Viettel Corporation, VN, source_asn:7552'",
              "@version" => "1",
            "@timestamp" => "2016-11-23T15:56:13.338Z",
                  "host" => "iMac.local",
                  "feed" => "openbl",
    "reported_source_ip" => "115.79.215.79",
       "source_cymru_cc" => "VN",
           "source_time" => "2016-06-25T11:15:14+00:00",
              "feed_url" => "http://www.openbl.org/lists/date_all.txt",
              "taxonomy" => "Other",
      "observation_time" => "2016-11-20T22:51:25",
             "source_ip" => "115.79.215.79",
       "source_registry" => "apnic",
      "source_allocated" => "2008-07-17",
     "source_bgp_prefix" => "115.79.192.0/19",
                  "type" => "blacklist",
        "source_as_name" => "VIETEL-AS-AP",
               "Viettel" => "Corporation",
            "source_asn" => "7552'"
}
```

Comment: The solution seems interesting; wont mutate get rid of the 'u' char in the host field?

Comment: Yes, of course, the regexp needs to be a bit more clever than that, but you get the idea ;-) Let me update that...

Comment: There you go, no more issues

Comment: Superb, will try it.

Comment: Already tried it, excellent. Took the liberty to add to your answer the exclusion of {}.